# How to create a empty HiveList in constructor function?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I want to create an empty HiveList for my Hive class to make a relation with another Hive class. But I cannot make a default value at the constructor. I think I am doing this wrong. Unfortunately the Hive docs does not cover this issue.

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Account extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String name;
  @HiveField(1)
  int amount;

  @HiveField(2)
  HiveList<History> history; // Want to make this list

  Account({
    required this.name,
    required this.amount,
    this.history = [] as HiveList<History>, // Error Here
  });
}
```

Comment: any update on this issue?

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)

class Account extends HiveObject {

@HiveField(0)

String name;

@HiveField(1)

int amount;

@HiveField(2)

HiveList<History> history; 

Account({

required this.name,

required this.amount,

this.history = const HiveList<History>.empty(), 

});

}
```

Comment: The class 'HiveList' doesn't have a constant constructor 'empty'.